# How to run Android studio on ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: application-development, android, 17.04

I'm trying to run Android studio on my laptop I have download android studio from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html?gclid=Cj0KEQiAm-CyBRDx65nBhcmVtbIBEiQA7zm8lWCaBd9n9KYYunFXxXsQCPojBVHk5eIH4p9CWM1eLfUaAmd28P8HAQ) and I have downloaded the SDK tool package separately I tried to run android studio from the .sh file and when I do it works but when I try to start a new project it says that I don't have the SDK here's what happens. [image: error]
When I try to correct the error by going to 'configure' > 'project defaults' > 'project structure' and then trying to choose the SDK by giving the program the directory for the SDKs that I have downloaded from the previous link it says that 'SDK does not contain any platforms' could someone please help me to start android studio please.
my system is ubuntu 17.04 64bit.
Thank you for reading.
***UPDATE***
here's what happens when I try to choose sdks or download them from sdk manager:
https://ibb.co/fVMH6a

https://ibb.co/eoen6a

https://ibb.co/d5NDev

Answer (score 0):

You need to install at least one SDK

Click on configure and select SDK Manager. Select one sdk and install

[image]

Comment: [here's](http://imgur.com/a/SQ1Mp) what happens when I open sdk manager.  
there's nothing to install.

Comment: click edit and set the path `/home/username/android-sdk/sdk`

Comment: please take a look at the update

Comment: clear everything and reinstall with sudo